# Converting quaternion to motor causes candy wrapping

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, programming, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

I have an animated model that I am trying to animate using PGA motors.

The animation mostly works but I am noticing that some of my motors seem to have an angle that is exactly 180 degrees off from what is should be, for example:

[image][image]

In between these 2 images the model's leg twists in a single frame, before the twist you can see some weird deformation along the leg, after the twist the leg looks ok.

A perhaps clearer example:

[image]

In here you can see the tibia pointing in the exact opposite direction it should.

This is how I am turning my data into motors:

```
fn quaternion_to_rotor(rotation : &Quatf) -> MultiVec3D
{
    let mut rot = MultiVec3D::zero();
    *rot.s_mut() = rotation.coords.w;
    *rot.e23_mut() = -rotation.coords.x;
    *rot.e31_mut() = -rotation.coords.y;
    *rot.e12_mut() = -rotation.coords.z;

    rot
}

fn vector_to_translator(trans : &Vec3) -> MultiVec3D
{
    let mut translator = MultiVec3D::zero();
    *translator.e01_mut() = -0.5 * trans.x;
    *translator.e02_mut() = -0.5 * trans.y;
    *translator.e03_mut() = -0.5 * trans.z;
    *translator.s_mut() = 1.0;

    translator
}
```

I trust the data and I mostly trust the code, I suspect that there is an ambiguity as to how quaternions can be turned into motors. My understanding is that quaternions can only represent the shortest rotation around an axis but rotors can represent either, so I think what might be happening is that sometimes I get the short rotation and sometimes I get the long rotation.

Is there a way for me to assert that a rotor is representing the shortest possible rotation around its axis?

Some further exploration shows me that the problem is when I convert matrices to quaternions (for the rotation) I am getting major numerical issues. So the solution seems to be to find a robust matrix to quaternion algorithm.

Comment: "gimbal lock" effect ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I don't think rotors can gimbal lock, afaik

Comment: You can do "short" and "long" rotations with either, its simply a matter of whether or not your path is $t \mapsto e^{t\theta B/2}$ or $t \mapsto e^{-t\theta B/2}$, where $B$ is either a bivector or quaternion. The subalgebra generated by $1, e_1e_2, e_2e_3, e_3e_1$ is isormorphic to the quaternions.

Comment: I think your `quaternion_to_rotor` is correct; quaternions are left-handed while your bivectors are right-handed, so that is where the minus signs are coming from. Something else to be careful about is which side of your sandwich has the minus sign, i.e. $$ e^{-\theta B/2}ve^{\theta B/2} \quad\text{vs.}\quad e^{\theta B/2}ve^{-\theta B/2}. $$ If your convention is that $\theta e_1e_2/2$ represents a rotation by $\theta$ taking $e_1$ towards $e_2$ the short way, then I think you want the first variant with the minus sign on the left, but you should work out some examples.

Comment: Since its mostly working though, without more details I would guess you matrix-to-quaternion conversion is the issue.

Comment: It definitely is, I tried an iterative method and a direct one, the iterative one is producing semi dicent results when I make it do a lot of iterations, but some twitching still happens, the direct one just seem utterly broken for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being the use of an iterative method to extract the rotation matrix. The proper solution is to use this formula:

https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToQuaternion/

```
float tr = m00 + m11 + m22

if (tr > 0) { 
  float S = sqrt(tr+1.0) * 2; // S=4*qw 
  qw = 0.25 * S;
  qx = (m21 - m12) / S;
  qy = (m02 - m20) / S; 
  qz = (m10 - m01) / S; 
} else if ((m00 > m11)&(m00 > m22)) { 
  float S = sqrt(1.0 + m00 - m11 - m22) * 2; // S=4*qx 
  qw = (m21 - m12) / S;
  qx = 0.25 * S;
  qy = (m01 + m10) / S; 
  qz = (m02 + m20) / S; 
} else if (m11 > m22) { 
  float S = sqrt(1.0 + m11 - m00 - m22) * 2; // S=4*qy
  qw = (m02 - m20) / S;
  qx = (m01 + m10) / S; 
  qy = 0.25 * S;
  qz = (m12 + m21) / S; 
} else { 
  float S = sqrt(1.0 + m22 - m00 - m11) * 2; // S=4*qz
  qw = (m10 - m01) / S;
  qx = (m02 + m20) / S;
  qy = (m12 + m21) / S;
  qz = 0.25 * S;
}
```